# Traversing XML object with jQuery using find contains and filtering out exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlnode, jquery-filter

In my programming logic, I have followed a particular XML specification. Now, a new XML specification has been handed down and I have to accommodate both. In particular, there is a line of jQuery code I use to select a particular set of nodes.

```
// i is a number. XType is some made-up construct to illustrate the problem.
// Here, I am selecting all Track tags with the above condition.
trackMatches = $(xmlObj).find("XType:contains(" + i + ")").parent();
```

Old XML specification (I only included the relevant info, and I used ellipses to show that there are more tags not shown).

```
<Record>
    <Title>Record Title</Title>
    <TotalTracks>10</TotalTracks>
    <Tracks>
         <Track>
             <XType>1</XType>
             ...
             <Coordinates>
                 <Coordinate>
                     <X>100</X>
                     <Y><50</Y>
                 </Coordinate>
             </Coordinates>
         </Track>
         ...
    </Tracks>
</Record>
```

New XML specification

```
<Record>
    <Title>Record Title</Title>
    <TotalTracks>10</TotalTracks>
    <Tracks>
         <Track>
             <XType>1</XType>
             ...
             <Coordinates>
                 <Coordinate>
                     <XType>1</XType>
                     <X>100</X>
                     <Y><50</Y>
                 </Coordinate>
             </Coordinates>
         </Track>
         ...
    </Tracks>
</Record>
```

Because of this altered XML specification, the line of code above will select all Track and Coordinate tags because the XType tag is now a child of both, whereas it was just a child of the Track tag in the original specification.

I want to maintain selecting just Track tags. Is it possible to execute a jQuery find and filter out exceptions? In this case, the exception would be where it matches the Coordinate tag and filter those out, leaving just Track tag matches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: One way would be to replace .parent() with .closest and a relevant selector. Another would be to add to the original selector to have it look for children of `Track`, or to have it directly look for `Track` elements that contain the specified child node.

Comment: Thank you. I like the suggestion using .closest. For the second question, I know you can use multiple selectors in a .find, which is like an OR. But how do you perform an AND with .find?

Comment: I changed it to `$(dispPartsXml).find("Track").children("XType:contains(1)").parent()`. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I mean like conditional statement, i.e. if (a==b and c==d). It might be a moot point, since you found the answer to the original question. I recall multiple selectors is similar to an OR conditional statement. But I don't recall if it's possible to perform a .find operation where all conditions must be true (aka AND). Thank you.

Comment: And would simply be no space or comma. For example, div.foobar says select elements where `nodeType==div AND classNames contains foobar`